# Custom module does not translates admin panel

Tags: localisation

I created a custom module and it does not translate grid columns or header. 
Here is my config.xml

```
<config>
...
    <frontend>
        <translate>
          <modules>
            <syncreports>
                <files>
                    <default>Mycompany_Syncreports.csv</default>
                </files>
            </syncreports>
        </modules>
       </translate>
    </frontend>
...
</config>
```

In app/locale/en_US/Mycompany_Syncreports.csv

```
"Synchronization reports123", "Reports"
```

And this is how I call it:

```
$this->_headerText = Mage::helper('syncreports')->__('Synchronization reports123');
```

This is how it looks in admin panel:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just move the definition of your translation file to , because translation file which is defined in frontend area will not be used in admin panel. You can use the same file for both ares but you need to extend config for that.

```
<adminhtml>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <syncreports>
                <files>
                    <default>Mycompany_Syncreports.csv</default>
                </files>
            </syncreports>
       </modules>
</translate>
```

Comment: Great, it works :) I forgot that it should be inside adminhtml tags